# Ruby Koala fql_multiquery parser error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-fql, koala

Sending 10 queries to Facebook's REST API. Calling the REST API through Koala's fql_multiquery function with the following as the input hash:

```
{"query11"=>"SELECT page_id, name, fan_count, page_url FROM page WHERE name='Wyoming Area Sec Center' ORDER BY fan_count DESC LIMIT 1", "query12"=>"SELECT page_id, name, fan_count, page_url FROM page WHERE name='Wyoming Area High School Exeter PA' ORDER BY fan_count DESC LIMIT 1", ...}
```

Queries all seem well-formed but Koala returns with:

```
Koala::Facebook::APIError: 601: Parser error: unexpected 's' at position 73.
```

Anybody run into this error code before?

Comment: oops! this is the problem:

    {"query18"=>"SELECT page_id, name, fan_count, page_url FROM page WHERE name='Governor's Academy' ORDER BY fan_count DESC LIMIT 1"}

The apostrophe in Governor's Academy is unescaped. This can be solved by simply escaping the FQL query inputs with something like str.gsub(/\\|'/) { |c| "\\#{c}" }

Answer (score 1):

oops! this is the problem:

```
{"query18"=>"SELECT page_id, name, fan_count, page_url FROM page WHERE name='Governor's Academy' ORDER BY fan_count DESC LIMIT 1"}
```

The apostrophe in Governor's Academy is unescaped. This can be solved by simply escaping the FQL query inputs with something like

```
str.gsub(/\\|'/) { |c| "\\#{c}" }
```

Comment: Can you explain your regular expression? I face the same issue and even though I escape my apostrophe with an extra one, it still does not work. Thanks!